# Supervisorctl can only run on root directory in docker

Tags: docker, supervisord

I started a Debian docker container, installed supervisosrd and started it.

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

When attaching into the container and check the status through supervisorctl, I found supervisorctl can only run on **/**. 

 
Following is the error message.

```
root@abcdd:~# docker exec -it 1a52 bash
root@1a52e1e42a0d:/# supervisorctl                                                                                 
mongodb                          RUNNING    pid 14, uptime 0:48:50
supervisor> 

root@1a52e1e42a0d:/# cd /opt/
root@1a52e1e42a0d:/opt# supervisorctl 
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

This is my supervisord.conf.

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
logfile_maxbytes=5MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
minfds=1024
minprocs=200

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:mongodb]
command = /monstor/bin/startup.sh
directory = /monstor/bin
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs = 16
startretries = 5
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

How can I set supervisorctl run anywhere? Thanks.

Comment: Does `supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisord.conf` work when in a different directory?

Comment: Yes, it works when in a different directory.  Is this mean `supervisorctl` can't find the default configuration file?

Comment: Try putting the config in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` instead of `/etc/supervisord.conf` and see if that helps